# Clock and volume are not showing on my second monitor

Tags: windows-10, audio

I am running windows 10 on an HP Intel core i5 processor.  My icons on the right side of my bottom taskbar are no longer showing.  Sound volume, Network, etc.

Comment: It is by-design behavior if your dual monitors are "Extend" mode. Those icons only show in the main monitor taskbar

Answer (score 2):

That's the way dual monitors work.  Those icons will only show on the main monitor.

You can change your main monitor by going to display settings, clicking on the monitor you want to change to the main monitor, and checking the "Make this my main monitor" checkbox.